# Can you kill a golem with passwall?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, monsters

Assuming you're within range of a golem can you cast [passwall](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/passwall.htm) on it to kill/destroy it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***Passwall* doesn't do damage**. I can see an argument whereby you might be able to open a hole through an especially large golem or colossus, if it were large enough to be perceived as a "wall", but this wouldn't actually harm the golem, just change its shape temporarily.

I can see some possible creative uses for this effect. For example, you could order a golem to plant itself between you and an opposing party, open a hole to shoot arrows or spells at your opponents, then close it again to gain cover. But in terms of actually destroying the golem, I don't think it would work.

Comment: I would agree it wouldn't do damge. If you did a passwall, as you stated, through a large golem's head and the body falls/moves I'd say when the spells ends the head would fall in the area in which the spell was cast. Although a golem isn't alive so it can't die I'd say losing your head makes it so you can't have senses to act upon and a golem isn't usually very smart so it should either fall or just stand there without a head.

Answer (score 26):

> You create a passage through wooden, plaster, or stone **walls**,

<sup>(**emphasis** mine)</sup>

A golem is not a wall, no matter what it is made of, and therefore *passwall* does nothing to it.

Comment: As DM, I would make exception if golem would [actually be made of walls](https://wiki.mabinogiworld.com/images/0/06/Giant_Castle_Wall_Golem.jpg), but that golem is from another game so we would be in houserule territory anyway.

Comment: @KRyan wall:  a thing perceived as a protective or restrictive barrier.
 By definition a golem could fall into the category of "wall", based on a dictionary definition of wall. Now it's up to how you wish to interpret that word.

Comment: @NationWidePants I absolutely refuse to get into that debate; I consider it spurious and a waste of everyone’s time. If you want to edit your question to focus on it, I will leave my answer as it is, downvote your question as “not useful,” and vote to close it as off-topic since it would be a philosophical semantic argument about the definition of an English word, not a question about game rules.

Comment: @NationWidePants I gotta agree with KRyan here. Seriously, if you're going to go *there*, why bother with a *passwall* spell? If that golem is impeding your further progress, just render the golem moot by casting on yourself the spell [*freedom of movement.*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsFtoG.html#freedom-of-movement)

Comment: A C++ golem compiled with `-Wall` would also qualify.

Comment: @Yakk Were a C++ golem complied in such a way, doesn't that mean somebody already passed `-Wall` to it?

Comment: I am reminded of how a *phase door* spell, which also only works on walls, will kill a Xorn that is currently passing through a stone wall.  Not quite the same, though.

Comment: @Yakk If there was a C++ golem, isn't it better to compile it without `-Wall`, so that it could summon friendly nasal demons? Those are nasty stuff.